# Sell Tax keeps changing on coin scanners and trading websites , is it because of low LP for test tokens?

Tags: bsc

I am testing a token I am going to launch, but I wanted to make sure things were okay and it was getting good scores first. One thing that baffled me was that the sell tax keeps changing on every transaction, at least the sell tax that is shown on websites like poocoin, dextools etc. Sometimes they dont even match on all of the websites. I have kept the fee at 2% but they went as high as 6% at some point in the life of the token.
Is this because of low LP? I have only set 0.1 BNB to 100 million coins. And holders have bought large chunks of it. Will setting large LP during live launch fix this issue?

contract: https://bscscan.com/address/0x19633cDaa50a29738cBadF6004F5daa0FE8587DB

Comment: Can you share the contract code? Without the code it will be just speculation.

Comment: https://bscscan.com/address/0x19633cDaa50a29738cBadF6004F5daa0FE8587DB Yes this is the contract

Answer (score 0):

It changes because your contract is probably selling the tokens it catches from the tax every time it reaches a certain quantity. Some variable like swapTokenAt. So dextools calculâtes the tax based on the value of the tokens when they get swapped out by the contract, usually on a sell. So, the tax it calculates ends up being slightly different from the way the tax is tax is set in the contract.

Didn’t read your contract, but I’ve seen this before and that was the issue.